# Getting "Program type already present" Error When Building Signed APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, exoplayer

I added FFmpeg extension to my ExoPlayer implementation and started getting
the following error when trying to generate a signed APK:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsCollector$Factory
```

I can generate a debug APK without problems. I tried to see the dependencies using `./gradlew app:dependencies`, however I cannot see what's wrong and which configuration to examine.

I don't see where and which ExoPlayer library is added as duplicate.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.acompany.anandroitvapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 18
        versionName "0.9.18_"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-leanback-v17:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-tv-provider:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    // Injections
    //compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12'
    //Retrofit Dependencies
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-leanback:2.6.1'
    implementation project(':exoplayer-extension-ffmpeg')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    /* optional: for detailed logging */
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```